# Struts2 List cannot be resolved for view

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am using struts 2 and I have set up my code like this:

Action class:

```
public class OrderDetailAction extends BaseActionSupport {

    private Collection<ShippingAddress> shippingAddressList;

    <the getters and setters here>

    private Collection<ShippingAddress> billingAddressList;

    <the getters and setters here>


    public String displayCreate() {
        LOGGER.info("DISPLAY CREATE CALLED");
        populateForiegnFields();
        LOGGER.info("populate foreign fields done calling");
        return SUCCESS;
    }


    private void populateForiegnFields(){

        LOGGER.info("ENTERED POPULATE FOREIGN FIELDS");

        ShippingAddressService shippingAddressService = ServiceFactory.getInstance().getShippingAddressService();
        shippingAddressList = shippingAddressService.getShippingAddresss();
        if(shippingAddressList == null) {
            LOGGER.info("shipping address list IS NULL");
        } else {
            LOGGER.info("shipping address list IS NOT NULL. CONTENTS:");

        }
        getSession().put("shippingAddressList", shippingAddressList);

        billingAddressList = shippingAddressService.getShippingAddresss();

        if(billingAddressList == null) {
            LOGGER.info("billingAddressList IS NULL");
        } else {
            LOGGER.info("billingAddressList IS NOT NULL. CONTENTS:");

        }
        getSession().put("billingAddressList", billingAddressList);

    }
```

And the snippet of my Create Order Detail JSP is:

```
    <s:form>
                <div class="form-group">some other fields</div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <s:select label="SHIPPINGADDRESSID" list="shippingAddressList" listKey="ID" listValue="ID" name="shippingAddress" ></s:select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <s:select label="BILLINGADDRESSID" list="billingAddressList" listKey="ID" listValue="ID" name="billingAddress" ></s:select>
                </div>
                <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="action:createOrderDetail" value="submit" id="displayCreateOrderDetail_createOrderDetail"/>
            <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="action:getOrderDetails" value="cancel" id="displayOrderDetail_getOrderDetails" />
    </s:form>
```

The error I am getting is this:

> tag 'select', field 'list', name 'shippingAddress': The requested list
>   key 'shippingAddressList' could not be resolved as a
>   collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type

But what confuses me, especially after I looked up this error on other posts 
 people suggested that the shippingAddressList may never have been instantiated but when I checked the log files that I wrote above, it was not null and at one point, I also logged the values from shippingAddressList.

Are there other reasons I could be getting this error?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is that jsp result of `OrderDetailAction` ? Do you have `public Collection<ShippingAddress> getShippingAddressList()` on it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by result of `orderDetailAction` but yes, shippingAddressList has public getters and setters though. When i checked the log files, when the JSP page was loaded, it was calling methods inside of `orderDetailAction`.

Comment: I meant if that above jsp has been set as the result of the above action in `struts.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

First Remove Collection and instead use List.

```
    private List<ShippingAddress> shippingAddressList;
    <the getters and setters here>
    private List<ShippingAddress> billingAddressList;
    <the getters and setters here>
```

I am not sure why you are putting these two list on session. They will already be on value stack.

I believe your `ShippingAddress` class have `ID` property.

Answer (score 0):

Oh boy so here is the error I was making. To make sure people don't run into this headache:

my getters and setters for my shippingAddressList and my billingAddressList were as follows:

```
get**s**hippingAddressList(); set**s**hippingAddressList()
```

and

```
get**b**illingAddressList(); set**b**illingAddressList()
```

The issue here was that the casing was not proper. Because it was not proper camel case, struts was never able to call the getters and setters.